# Lodash FP flow always returns any

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, lodash

I am trying to use lodash FP with typescript for a function typeline. However whenever i try to use flow and plug in any functions I always end up with a value of type any. Even if i just use a single function.
In the example, the result is correctly type as `string` if i just use the `map` function but I end up with `any` if i plug it into flow.

The result is the same and its correct.

How can I ensure that the result type of `flow` is the actual type?[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pjup5f?file=index.ts

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/126014)

Comment: Looks like `flow` doesn't have an overload for only one function, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-97gbho?file=index.ts). If you use two or more then it works.

Comment: maybe consider avoiding `lodash-fp` altogether and try something more sufficient like `fp-ts`? [npmtrends](https://npmtrends.com/fp-ts-vs-lodash-fp)

Comment: Lodash has pretty bad Typescript typings for stuff like this, I second the suggestion to use something more purpose-built for TS like `fp-ts`